# 301 редирект, убрать все параметры

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно сделать 301 редирект через *.htaccess* со страниц с get параметрами на страницы без них. Пример:

```
/любая_страница/?любой_параметр
```

Должен идти редирект на страницу:

```
/любая_страница/
```

Без `get` параметра, за исключением страниц из каталога `/search`:

```
/search/?q=любой_текст
```

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, какие зарпосы не должны модифицироваться: только для каталога `search`, только для параметра `q` или для комбинации из каталога `search` и параметра `q`?

Comment: для каталога `search`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

например, так:

```
$ cat .htaccess
rewriteengine on

rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search/
rewriterule ^(.*)$ /$1? [l,r=301]
```

проверка:

```sh
$ wget -S --spider 'http://localhost/blabla/' |& grep -E '  (HTTP|Loc)'
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
$ wget -S --spider 'http://localhost/blabla/?x' |& grep -E '  (HTTP|Loc)'
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Location: http://localhost/blabla/
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
$ wget -S --spider 'http://localhost/search/?x' |& grep -E '  (HTTP|Loc)'
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```